# Compare columns in 2 Oracle 11g tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 tables in Oracle 11g one containing the actual source data and the other masked data.

The table has 1260000 rows approximately.

The column I am comparing is Varchar.

I am trying to check if all the data has been masked to value different from the original data.

I am performing a select query with 2 conditions on the join 1. with a unique row identifier 2. the value I am trying to compare.

The query never returns upon execution.

Is there a way to get an output where I can see the rows where the value is the same in both the table ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question.

For example, I created a "duplicate" of Scott's `EMP` table and "masked" names:

```
SQL> create table emp2 as select * From emp;

Table created.

SQL> update emp2 set ename = translate(ename, 'AEIOU', '98765');

14 rows updated.

SQL> select empno, ename from emp2 order by empno;

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SM7TH
      7499 9LL8N
      7521 W9RD
      7566 J6N8S
      7654 M9RT7N
      7698 BL9K8
      7782 CL9RK
      7788 SC6TT
      7839 K7NG
      7844 T5RN8R
      7876 9D9MS
      7900 J9M8S
      7902 F6RD
      7934 M7LL8R

14 rows selected.
```

To check which names are different:

```
SQL> select a.empno, a.ename, b.ename
  2  from emp a join emp2 b on a.empno = b.empno
  3  where a.ename <> b.ename
  4  order by a.empno;

     EMPNO ENAME      ENAME
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      SM7TH
      7499 ALLEN      9LL8N
      7521 WARD       W9RD
      7566 JONES      J6N8S
      7654 MARTIN     M9RT7N
      7698 BLAKE      BL9K8
      7782 CLARK      CL9RK
      7788 SCOTT      SC6TT
      7839 KING       K7NG
      7844 TURNER     T5RN8R
      7876 ADAMS      9D9MS
      7900 JAMES      J9M8S
      7902 FORD       F6RD
      7934 MILLER     M7LL8R

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Or, in your case, as you'd want to see values that aren't changed, you'd modify line #3 to

```
where a.ename = b.ename
```

Comment: Thank You. This is what I am doing, except that I have 6+6 (before and after) other columns in the select query and the query never returns.

Comment: I don't understand what "6+6 (before and after)" means. As you're joining two tables on some column (primary key?), are they indexed? If it were a primary key, Oracle would create an index implicitly if it didn't exist, but - if it it weren't - then check for index(es), gather tables' statistics, check explain plan.